# Receiving a web page after HttpWebRequest "POST"

Tags: c#, json, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am performing the following HttpWebRequest:

```
      private static void InvokeHealthCheckApi()
    {
        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
        string sb = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(webRequest);
        webRequest.Method = "GET";
        webRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        webRequest.UserAgent =
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36";
        webRequest.CookieContainer = cookieJar;

        using (HttpWebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {

            File.AppendAllText("C:\\httpResponse1.txt", response.Headers.ToString());
            File.AppendAllText("C:\\httpResponse2.html", reader.ReadToEnd());

        }


    }
```

The response from the request is coming back as web page that reads:
"Script is disabled. Click Submit to continue."
(Submit Button)

After clicking the submit button i get a prompt that reads:
"Do you want to open or save healthcheck.json(297 bytes) from fr74a87d9.work.corp.net?

After clicking the Open button I receive the json data that I am expecting to receive.

My question is how do I parse the response to get to the json data that I need? Is it normal to get the web page as the initial response and have to drill down to get the json response? StreamReader can't parse the response because it's a web page and not json data.

Comment: whatever site you're hitting is expecting something else to be done than what you're doing in your request. you have to replicate EXACTLY what is sent client<->server in a browser when you're doing scraping.

Comment: Thanks Marc for the response.  I'm not sure what I'm not replicating in my code that the site is expecting. Here are the steps my code is doing:

Comment: 1) HttpWebRequest "GET" to get the webpage and the associated cookie info. 2) Populate the webpage formData (password, userid) 3) HttpWebRequest "POST" to the login page  4) Now that I'm logged in I do a GET on the Web API controller url

Answer (score 0):

I found a resolution to my problem here:               http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/applisec/2013/06/03/passive-federation-client/